# Como compilar apps Xamarin en IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Mi pregunta es muy simple y es la siguiente:
Es posible compilar app creadas con Xamarin en IOS desde Windows? Supongo que si ya que para eso está hecho Xamarin, pero al intentar ejecutar un simple HolaMundo en un dispositivo IOS salta el siguiente error:

```
The IDB Local Agent couldn't be started and the maximum allowed attempts have been reached.
```

Busqué durante un rato soluciones en internet, pero solo aparecían soluciones para gente que programa en Mac, de ahí mi duda de si se puede hacer en Windows. Hasta en la pagina de Microsoft corrigen el error solo para Mac.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Si tienes un iPhone, puedes hacer que se ejecuten ahí. Lo recomendable es que tengas una Mac en la red

Comment: Es posible compilar pero no es posible probar, una App, ya que necesitas una mac para poder levantar tu app, lo hagas con Emulador o con Telefono fisico. Siempre debes emparejar una mac.